# Commerce order confirmation message with shipping service

Tags: commerce, message-subscribe

I'm sending confirmation message of a commerce order via [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify). I want to display the selected shipping service in the email.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using *Commerce Message* module for this.

One way to do this is by adding your own *token*. In your custom module (MYMODULE) add this code (I have too many comments just for educational reasons):

```
// Set arguments for our custom token !order-shipping
function MYMODULE_message_presave($message) {
  if (!empty($message->mid)) {
    return;
  }
  $message->arguments['!order-shipping'] = array(
    'callback' => 'commerce_message_order_shipping',
    'pass message' => TRUE,
  );
}

/**
 * Message callback; Show Order Shipping Service label (!order-shipping).
 *
 * @param $message
 *   The Message entity.
 */
function commerce_message_order_shipping(Message $message) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('message', $message);
  // Get order id from current commerce message
  $order_id = $wrapper->message_commerce_order->getIdentifier();
  // Get order from order_id
  $order_wrapper = commerce_order_load($order_id);
  // Get the line items. Shipping service is a line item (like product, discount etc)
  $line_items = $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items['und'];

  // Loop through the line items so you find the shipping service
  foreach ($line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
    $line_item_id = $line_item_wrapper['line_item_id'];
    $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id);
    //dpm($line_item);
    if(isset($line_item->commerce_shipping_service)) {
      // This is want we need, the shipping service label
      $shipping_service = $line_item->line_item_label;
    }
  }

  return $shipping_service;
}
```

Then in your message body add you new token `!order-shipping`.

Notice that this method works for other line items too... Also, it works for other modules that send emails (such as [commerce_email](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_email)) but with some difference in the hook function - currently `hook_message_presave($message)` -.

Credits to this issue: http://drupalcommerce.org/node/10096